# Scraping web in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I had scraped the old version of mjzj.com search page looking if there were results or not looking for a specific div:

```
quote_page = "https://m.mjzj.com/ce-ping-bao-guang-tai/sou-suo?query=XXXXXXX"
page = urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
divcla = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mt-2 mb-2 reviewer-exposure-search-result-info"})
```

But the page has updated: the source code has changed to JavaScript.

The page: https://mjzj.com/newmjzj/checkevaluate?query=xxxxx

The result of the query I'm interested in is under this "button":

[image: view image]

I just need to look if results exist or not (I don't need the content).

What do I need to change in my code?